# How to validate a dynamic list of nested components form group?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a component which contains a dynamic list of nested component. In each nested component there is a form group to validate it. here's the code for the parent component:

Parent Item-form-component:

```
export class ItemFromComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChildren('item') items: QueryList<ItemComponent>;

 itemList: Item[] = [];

 constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.addItem();
 }
 itemListValidator(items: QueryList<ItemComponent>): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
   if (items) {
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (items[i].itemFormGroup.invalid) {
         return {'isNotValid': true};
      }
    }
     return null;
   } else {
     return null;
   }
  };
 }

  addItem(): void {
    const item = new Item();
    this.itemList.push(item);
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.itemsFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      itemListFormControl: ['', this.itemListValidator(this.items)]
    });
  }
```

Parent template:

```
<app-ribbon text="New product items"></app-ribbon>
<form class="form-wrapper" [formGroup]="itemsFormGroup">
  <button mat-fab class="add-item-button" color="primary" matTooltip="Add one more item" (click)="addItem()">
    <mat-icon aria-label="Add one empty item to the list">add</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <mat-accordion class="example-headers-align">
    <div *ngFor="let item of itemList; let i = index">
      <app-item #item
                (deleteItem)="removeItem($event)"
                (cloneItem)="cloneItem($event)"
                [item]="item"
                [index]="i"
                [expanded]="i === 0 ? true : false">
      </app-item>
    </div>
  </mat-accordion>
</form>
```

The hard part here is that the number of item is dynamic so I tried to validate these component with a custom validator function which takes in parameters a list of the child component. If one of them is not yet valid it should return an error for the user.

Since the list of child component is initially empty my custom validator always return null because the list is undefined. Further more, my custom validator validate only on init. I need it to validate the list everytime the user add a new input in the child component. Maybe an event emitter from the child?

Is there a better way to achieve this? Should I pass the form group to every children?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a custom form component it is recommended to implement [NgValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor).

Here is a [how-to](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/).

You can then use your custom component like an `<input>` field.

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <app-item formControlName="user">
    </app-item>
</div>
```

And the bindings for validation will also work.

`<span *ngIf="form?.get('user').invalid">Field Invalid</span>`

ts:

```
public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({ 
  user: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, customValidator]) 
})
```